# How do I spawn a shell command from X monad and get it output?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, xmonad

I want to write a shutdown menu for XMonad, and bind it to a key combo.

So the ingredients seem to be these following.

1. A command, so a `String`, that can be executed in a shell to open the menu. The user than chooses what to do (e.g. Suspend, Shutdown, ...), and the output of that executable will be a `String` as well, call it `choice`.
2. Then I'd have a pure `String -> String` function `f` to map the user decision to the command to run.
3. Finally I'd have to execute that `f choice :: String` which woud have no output.

And this whole thing should be done by XMonad, so I assume I would have to add `("M-r", shutdownmenu)` to the `mappings` I pass to `` def `additionalKeysP` mappings ``. That `shutdownmenu` function is the one that should perform the steps above.

But to do that, I'd need, I believe,

- a `String -> X String` function to launch the program that asks the user to choose what to do; I though I would find something in [`XMonad.Util.Run`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.1/docs/XMonad-Util-Run.html), but no function there seems to have the signature *and* semantics that I need,
- the `String -> String` function, which is the easy thing,
- the `String -> X ()` function, for which [`spawn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.2/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:spawn) seems to fit the bill.

What I don't find is the first of these ingredients, [`getCommandOutput`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.1/docs/XMonad-Prompt-Man.html#v:getCommandOutput) looks similar to what I need, but it retuns in the `IO` moand instead of in the `X` monad or a generic monad `m`, so I can't really do much with it in the `X` monad.

Or can I?

Comment: The function you're looking for might be `runProcessWithInput` in `XMonad.Util.Run`. `X` is an instance of `MonadIO`, so you can use it there. [`XMonad.Util.Dmenu`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.1/docs/XMonad-Util-Dmenu.html) is probably close to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I had seen that, but I was mislead by the signature. `FilePath` made me think I'd have to write the script in an actual file (that's why "_and_ semantics"). But `FilePath` is just an alias for `String`! I guess the use of that alias is a bit misleading, considering the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.1/docs/src/XMonad.Util.Run.html#runProcessWithInput). I mean, the arg is named `cmd` indeed, not `path` or something. :/

Comment: I will definitely give a look. I've never used `dmenu`, but probably it fits the bill, thanks!

Comment: `FilePath` looks right to me in that signature: one executes files, not strings. Parsing a string into a program to run and a list of arguments is typically done by the shell, not by low-level "execute a program" functions. What's an example of a String you were hoping to run?

Comment: @amalloy, thinking of a `rofi -dmenu ops` command. But @duplode is suggesting something that does that out of the box I guess. As regards the name. The type name is `FilePath` and the name of the formal argument is `cmd`. However you look at it, one or the other is wrong, no?

Comment: @Enlico Yes, `cmd` is slightly imprecise (and `FilePath` is correct). If you want to run `rofi -dmenu ops`, you would pass *only* `rofi` as the `FilePath`, and the other arguments would be passed separately (in the `[String]` argument). N.B. there are various alternatives to spawning a separate process; check out `XMonad.Prompt` and its submodules.